# Issues with Rlang during Swirl Installation

Tags: r

When installing Swirl using R Studio on Windows 10 (64-bit), the Swirl package installs but the running library (swirl) cannot be found. The system gives an error that rlang gets removed while installing Swirl:

```
Error in rlang() : could not find function "rlang"
```

> install.packages("rlang")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/***/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

There is a binary version available but the source
  version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rlang  0.3.2  0.3.3              TRUE

installing the source package ‘rlang’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_0.3.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 859027 bytes (838 KB)
downloaded 838 KB

- installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
  ** package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** libs
  C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:230: warning: overriding recipe for target '.m.o'
  C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:223: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.m.o'
  c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c capture.c -o capture.o
  process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -IC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include -DNDEBUG -I./lib/ -O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c capture.c -o capture.o, ...) failed.
  make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
  make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:208: capture.o] Error 2
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'

Comment: This happens sometimes in Windows when you attempt to install a package when another R instance is open. I've done it plenty. Try shutting down all R/Rstudio sessions, restarting, `install.packages("rlang"); install.packages("swirl")`. Do you still get errors?

Comment: install.packages("rlang"); install.packages("swirl")  - Installing package into ‘C:/Users/**/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

installing the source package ‘rlang’

tdownloaded 335 KB

package ‘swirl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\satyajit\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpya1fmj\downloaded_packages
> library(swirl)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘rlang’

Comment: Have you tried installing from github?

Comment: Can you tell me how to install from  swirl or Rlang GITHUB please?

Comment: install.packages("swirl")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/satyajit/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/swirl_2.4.3.zip'

package ‘swirl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\satyajit\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpya1fmj\downloaded_packages
> library (swirl) Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘rlang’